# Set height of a flex item or extend base on content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this flex column container with two elements with classes .one and .two inside:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  height: 50vh;
  background: blue;
}

.two {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is when the .one's content is greater than 50vh it overlaps with the .two class, the .two class is a loading indicator, .one is the container with 50vh height so that when it is loading, the .two class stays on the same position, but I want to increase the height of .one class when it's contents are greater than 50vh and prevent it from overlapping on .two class, help?

Comment: @gpbaculio: For better understanding,  provides your complete code.

Comment: You have `height: 50px` set to your second element, but you are talking about `50vh`. Change it to a number that is less confusing - maybe `20px`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use min-height instead of height then .one container will take it's necessary space

```
.one {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: blue;
}
```